# Match data with previous row in pandas based on multiple conditi

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df as below

```
id      date  time  event  prod_code 
a1      201701  11   Prodpage  101538
a1      201701  11:01 basket   101538 
b1      201701  11:19  Prodpage 109
b1      201701  11:20  basket   1
```

I need to create a new column matched please find a pseudo-code below

```
df[matched] = if (value of id in 1st row = value of id in 2nd row, & \
              if date[1] = date[2] & event[1] = "prodpage", \
              event[2] = "basket" & prod_code[1] = prod_code[2] ,\
              "then matched" otherwise unmatched
```

so the output should be

```
id      date  time  event  prod_code   matched?
a1      201701  11   Prodpage  101538   
a1      201701  11:01 basket   101538   Matched 
b1      201701  11:19  Prodpage 109
b1      201701  11:20  basket   1       Not Matched
```

How to accomplish this in pandas

Comment: Do you always have two pairs of rows? Are there only ever two rows per `id`?

Comment: One good starting point might be to work in [df.duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with your `subset` as `['id','date','prod_code']` and `keep='last'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break down your logic into parts and combine multiple Boolean conditions at the end. For example, if you always have 2 values for each `id` and they are adjacent:

```
match_cols = ['id', 'date', 'prod_code']

m1 = df[match_cols] == df[match_cols].shift()
m2 = df['event'] == 'basket'
m3 = df['event'].shift() == 'Prodpage'

df['matched?'] = np.where(m1.all(1) & m2 & m3, 'matched', 'not matched')
df.loc[::2, 'matched?'] = ''

print(df)

   id    date   time     event  prod_code     matched?
0  a1  201701     11  Prodpage     101538             
1  a1  201701  11:01    basket     101538      matched
2  b1  201701  11:19  Prodpage        109             
3  b1  201701  11:20    basket          1  not matched
```